# How would I define the __m256i data type in Ada?

Tags: simd, ada, intrinsics, avx2, gnat

I am trying to write a library for AVX2 in Ada 2012 using the GNAT GCC compiler.
I have currently defined a data type Vec_256_Integer_32 like so:

```
type Vector_256_Integer_32 is array (0 .. 7) of Integer_32;
pragma Pack(Vec_256_Integer_32);
```

Note that I have aligned the array according to the 32 byte boundary indicated in Intel's documentation of the `_mm256_load_si256` intrinsic function from `immintrin.h`.

I would like to implement an operation that adds two of these arrays together using AVX2. The function prototype is as follows.

```
function Vector_256_Integer_32_Add (Left, Right : Vector_256_Integer_32) return Vector_256_Integer_32
```

My idea for implementing this function is to do this in three steps.

1. Load a and b using `_mm256_load_si256` into a local variable.
2. Perform the addition operation using `_mm256_add_epi32`.
3. Convert the result back into the `Vec_256_Unsigned_32` type using `_mm256_store_si256`.

Where I am confused is how I would create the __m256i data type in Ada to hold the intermediate results. Can someone please shed some light on this? Additionally, if you see any issues with my approach, any feedback is appreciated.

I have found the definition of __m256i in GCC (located at gcc/gcc/config/i386/avxintrin.h).

```
typedef long long __m256i __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32), __may_alias__));
```

However, here is where I am stuck as I am not sure how I would transfer this to Ada code.
I have found that the `__vector_size__` attribute is documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions).

Comment: `_mm256_load_si256` is the load intrinsics you want.  `_mm256_load_epi32` is a weirdly redundant version added with AVX-512.  Of course, if your Ada compiler doesn't know about them as built-in functions, or something you can define in terms of built-in functions, that doesn't help.  The whole point of intrinsics is that they mostly compile to single machine instructions (or to a load that can be a memory source operand for another instruction), not actual function calls.  I unfortunately don't know anything about Ada (the language), only its namesake.

Comment: This is an incidental question, not helpful to you: Your "pragma Pack" has two arguments. The Ada RM says it should have only one argument - the type to be packed. What is the meaning of the second argument, the number "32"? Does your Ada compiler have a non-standard, two-argument pragma Pack?

Comment: Another nit-pick: your declaration of the "add" function has the parameter type and parameter identifiers in the wrong order. You should have "a, b : Vec_256_Unsigned_32". Again, sorry for a comment that is not really answering your question...

Comment: A comment that may be useful to you: there is some auto-vectorization in GNAT/GCC, as described in https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_ugn/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/gnat_and_program_execution.html?highlight=simd#vectorization-of-loops. If that does not help you, I can only advise you to write the addition in assembly language, perhaps using the System.Machine_Code package that should be predefined in your GNAT.

Comment: re: your last edit: `_mm256_add_epi32` is the right intrinsic for signed or unsigned integers.  x86 is a 2's complement machine, so there's no separate instruction for signed or unsigned addition; it's the same binary operation.  The intrinsic names default to `epi` instead of `epu` for instructions where the same one works equally well on signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question after doing more research. Thank you for your input. I am posting this so hopefully someone else can get value from this.

Edit: I have adjusted my answer according to feedback from the commenter Peter Cordes.

For example, if you want to define a data type of 8 32-bit signed integers, you would write

```
type Vector_256_Integer_32 is array (0 .. 7) of Integer_32 with Convention => C, Alignment => 32;
```

The function to add the two vectors together would be defined as

```
function "+" (Left, Right: Vector_256_Integer_32) return Vector_256_Integer_32;
pragma Import (Intrinsic, "+", "__builtin_ia32_paddd256");
```

Note that I am using the GCC intrinsic, rather than the intrinsics from immintrin.h (because I am not aware how to import an intrinsic from that header file).

The documentation of `_mm256_add_epi32` states that the `vpaddd` instruction is used. The GCC `__builtin_ia32_paddd256` appears to translate to this instruction.

Below is an example Ada program and ads file.

avx2.ads

```
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;

package AVX2 is

   --
   -- Type Definitions
   --

   -- 256-bit Vector of 32-bit Signed Integers
   type Vector_256_Integer_32 is array (0 .. 7) of Integer_32;
   for Vector_256_Integer_32'Alignment use 32;
   pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Integer_32, "vector_type");
   pragma Machine_Attribute (Vector_256_Integer_32, "may_alias");

   --
   -- Function Definitions
   --

   -- Function: 256-bit Vector Addition of 32-bit Signed Integers
   function Vector_256_Integer_32_Add
     (Left, Right : Vector_256_Integer_32) return Vector_256_Integer_32 with
     Convention    => Intrinsic, Import => True,
     External_Name => "__builtin_ia32_paddd256";

end AVX2;
```

main.adb

```
with AVX2;        use AVX2;
with Interfaces;  use Interfaces;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   a, b, r : Vector_256_Integer_32;
begin
   for i in Vector_256_Integer_32'Range loop
      a (i) := 5 * (Integer_32 (i) + 5);
      b (i) := 12 * (Integer_32 (i) + 12);
   end loop;
   r := Vector_256_Integer_32_Add(a, b);
   for i in Vector_256_Integer_32'Range loop
      Put_Line
        ("r(i) = a(i) + b(i) = " & a (i)'Image & " + " & b (i)'Image & " = " &
         r (i)'Image);
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Here is an equivalent program in C. Note that this code has only been tested in GCC and is not necessarily the most efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    __m256i ma;
    __m256i mb;
    __m256i mr;
    int32_t a[8] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
    int32_t b[8] __attribute__((aligned(32)));
    int32_t r[8] __attribute__((aligned(32)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        a[i] = 5 * (i + 5);
        b[i] = 12 * (i + 12);
    }

    ma = _mm256_load_si256((void *const)a);
    mb = _mm256_load_si256((void *const)b);

    mr = _mm256_add_epi32(ma, mb);

    _mm256_store_si256((void *)r, mr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        printf("r[i] = a[i] + b[i] = %d + %d = %d\n", a[i], b[i], r[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Note that you need to make sure that GNAT can actually link with the intrinsics in immintrin.h.* - Maybe you've missed the point of C intrinsics.  They're wrappers for compiler built-ins, not library function.  There is nothing to link with. Look at code-gen for a C++ function: https://godbolt.org/z/48aYcPaez shows `__m256i f(__m256i a, __m256i b){ return _mm256_adds_epu8(a,b); }` compiling to `vpaddusb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1`; `ret`, since the args are passed and returned in AVX vector registers, and the intrinsic expands to one asm instruction.  Even in a debug build there's no call.

Comment: If you want to write C functions to call from Ada, write functions that take pointers to a whole array, and loop inside the C function.  Writing actual C functions like `struct wrap_m256i MM256_Adds_EPU8(const __m256i *, const __m256i *)` would be less efficient, and the load/store intrinsics would just be 32-byte memcpy so that's pretty much pointless.  You can't pass vectors by value unless your Ada compiler knows how to use SIMD vector types natively for function args / return values.

Comment: You should not need to use access types. Defining `function MM256_Load_SI256 (a : in out Vec_256_Unsigned_8) return M256u8 with ...;` or  `function MM256_Load_SI256 (a : aliased Vec_256_Unsigned_8) return M256u8 with ...;` will cause Ada to pass a pointer to the parameter.

Comment: C style notes: In modern C, you'd use `alignas(32) int32_t a[8];` and `#include <stdalign.h>`.  (Or use C11 `_Align()` without includes).  No need for a non-portable `__attribute__` to do something that's now standardized.  And you don't need to declare vars at the top of a function, so `__m256i ma = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i*)a);` when you're ready to use it would be typical (and considered better style by many).

Comment: Re: efficiency: the vector part is fine.  No downside to telling the compiler the loads/stores are aligned (by using `load` instead of `loadu` like you're doing) if you can align your data cheaply.  SIMD load right after scalar stores would likely create a store-forwarding stall, so extra latency, but this is just an example.  And a compiler might turn that init loop into a copy from a constant.  (Preferably with `vpmovzxbd` to pack the ints down to bytes in .rodata, but GCC isn't that clever, or doesn't choose to trade extra ALU work for space-saving.)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is to learn Ada, since 2/3 of your Ada declarations are invalid. Pragma Pack has only one argument (GNAT does not have an implementation-dependent version with two), and in Ada 12 you should usually use the aspect rather than the pragma. Alignment is specified otherwise. Ada does not have "function prototypes". The *function declaration* for your addition operation should be

```
function "+" (Left : in Vec_256_Unsigned_32; Right : in Vec_256_Unsigned_32) return Vec_256_Unsigned_32;
```

Ada has operator overloading and packages for encapsulation and namespace control, so you don't need prefixes on everything as you do in languages lacking these essential features.

IIUC, the C definition of __m256i defines an array of `long long` that occupies 32 bytes. Since Interfaces.C doesn't define an equivalent for `long long`, the Ada equivalent depends on the size of `long long`. If it's 64 bits, then it's equivalent to Interfaces.Integer_64, which is 8 bytes, so the Ada equivalent would be

```
type M256i is array (1 .. 4) of Interfaces.Integer_64 with Convention => C;
```

(Anything you pass to a C subprogram should be defined in Interfaces.C or its children, or declared with convention C.)

Since both M256i and Vec_256_Unsigned_32 are 32 bytes, you can convert between them using instances of Ada.Unchecked_Conversion.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I apologize for not being more careful. I just have a follow up question. Instead of using pragma Pack, would using the Alignment aspect/attribute. For example, would I write `for Vec_256_Unsigned_32'Alignment use 32` to align on the 32 byte boundary?

Comment: The GCC definition of `__m256i` as a vector of `long long` elements is purely an implementation detail.  Operations on it can use any element size from byte to 64-bit, or a byte-shift within 128-bit halves.  (`_mm256_bslli_epi128` - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pslldq).  In GNU C you *can* write stuff like `va += vb`, but that's considered bad practice vs. `va = _mm256_add_epi64(va, vb)` which is portable to MSVC as well.  `_mm256_add_epi8(va, vb)` uses 8-bit SIMD elements.  Intel's intrinsics API doesn't define operator overloads.

Comment: But anyway, yes, the object representation is a 32-byte vector.  It's passed by value in YMM registers, though, unlike C arrays.  And intrinsics aren't real functions, they don't exist in a library anywhere you can call them, they get inlined to a single instruction at the "call site" in a C program.  For example, the saturating u8 add the OP wants to use is defined in GCC's avx2intrin.h as `extern __inline __m256i
__attribute__ ((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))` with body `return (__m256i)__builtin_ia32_paddusb256 ((__v32qi)__A, (__v32qi)__B);`

Comment: GCC defines some vector types for internal use, like `__v32qi`, a vector of 32 quarter-integer elements.  The builtin function wants args of that type, so it casts to that.  From a different language that doesn't have its own AVX2 intrinsics, probably the best you can do is pass pointers to C functions you write yourself.  (Which should take pointer+length and loop in C, not do a function call for every vector and force multiple store/reload operands for every temporary vector!)